# On finding A-polynomials

Tags: knot-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-topology, computer-algebra

I have two questions to obtain the explicit forms of A-polynomials.

[Takata](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401068) used the mathematica pacage  qMultisum.m to obtain the recursion relation of the colored Jones polynomials for twist knots. As Stavros Garoufalidis and Xinyu Sun pointed out in [this paper](http://de.arxiv.org/abs/0802.4074), the simple use of the mathematica pacage qZeil.m, qMultisum.m does not give the recursion relation of minimal order. They made use of the method, so-called creative telescoping, to get the recursion relation of minimal order by using the certificat function.

> > 1. How do you implement this method in Mathematica, say, to get the recursion relation for $5_2$ and $6_1$ knots as in p.4 of [the paper](http://de.arxiv.org/abs/0802.4074)?

Recently, [Gukov, Sulkowski and Fuji](http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.1515v2) conjecture that, in the limit,
\begin{equation}
q = e^{\hbar} \to 1 \,, \qquad a = \text{fixed} \,, \qquad t = \text{fixed} \,, \qquad x = q^n = \text{fixed}
\end{equation}
the $n$-colored superpolynomials $P_n (K;a,q,t)$ exhibit the following ``large color'' behavior:
\begin{equation}
P_n (K;a,q,t) \;\overset{{n \to \infty \atop \hbar \to 0}}{\sim}\;
\exp\left( \frac{1}{\hbar} \int \log y \frac{dx}{x} \,+\, \ldots \right)
\end{equation}
where ellipsis stand for regular terms (as $\hbar \to 0$) and the leading term is given by
the integral on the zero locus of the super-$A$-polynomial:
\begin{equation}
A^{\text{super}} (x,y;a,t) \; = \; 0 \ .
\end{equation}

For example, the critical points of the leading term of colored superpolynomials of torus knots $T^{2,2p+1}$ are give by
\begin{eqnarray}
1 \; &=& \; -\frac{t^{-2-2p}(x-z_0)z_0^{-1-2p}(-1+t^2z_0)(1+ at^3 xz_0)}{(-1+z_0)(atx+z_0)(-1 +  t^2 x z_0)} \cr
y(x,t,a)&=&
\frac{a^p t^{2 + 2 p} (-1 + x) x^{1 + 2 p} (atx + z_0) (1 + a t^3 x z_0)}{(1 + a t^3 x) (x - z_0) (-1 + t^2 x z_0)} ,
\end{eqnarray}
which is written in Eq.(2.35) and (2.36). By eliminating $z_0$, you will obtain the super-$A$-polynomials for torus knots $T^{2,2p+1}$. Off course, it should be doable in principle, but

> > $2$. how can it be implemented explicitly to obtain the super-$A$-polynomials as in Table 5 of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.1515v2)? In other words, how do you explicitly eliminate $z_0$ in such a way that you will obtain the super-$A$-polynomials?

I have the same problem to obtain the $Q$-deformed $A$-polynomials from Eq.(A.21) in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.2182v1).

Comment: I would suggest adding some tag referencing computation, implementation, Mathematica, or even qmultisum.

Comment: Tags edited, with the desirable side-effect of bumping the question.